# How to handle dependencies of projects with different Scala versions?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have three Scala projects:

Project A - must have version 2.11.9 of Scala.

Project B - must have version 2.12.13 of Scala.

Common - the version does not matter.

Both Projects A and B use Common.

Is there any way to make it work other than compiling two times the Common project, with two different versions?

And if it's the only option, how can I manage it in the easiest way? Because going from one version to another in build.sbt means also to change the versions of many dependencies, and it is a mess.

Comment: Check sbt docs about cross building https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html . Set `crossScalaVersions` and run commands with `+` e.g `+ build` - yes multiple versions require compiling (and publishing if its a library) against each supported version.

Answer (score 2):

Like said in a comment, you want to use what is called **"cross building"** for your "common" project so that it's built and published for both Scala 2.11 and Scala 2.12.

**[SBT support this natively](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html)**.

*If later you have a more complex project structure you can have a look to an useful plugin called **[project-matrix](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-projectmatrix)** for cross building by generating  a SBT subproject for each Scala version (or actually other dimensions like JVM/JavaScript).*

As for dependencies, you should be using [the `%%` operator](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Getting+the+right+Scala+version+with) when defining dependencies so that the appropriate Scala version of the dependency is picked up automatically.